# UIImageView with aspectToFil and crop only top of the image

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift4

I have a vertically large long image, like 500pt x 1000pt.

And I am trying to display very bottom of the image.
So, I want to crop off top of the image.

But, `contentMode = aspectToFil` crops top and bottom of the image, and shows middle of the image.

There is explanation image below.

Is there any better way?

Note: I can not use `contentMode = bottom`. Because the image is pretty large.

[aspectToFil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN5h6.png)

Comment: Why does the image being large affect you using `bottom`?

Answer (score 1):

You can crop the image `CGImage.cropping(to: CGRect)`.

Set the origin of the `CGRect` to the upper right corner of where you want to begin cropping, and set the size to the size of the crop you want. Then initialize and image from that `cgImage`.

```
let foo = UIImage(named: "fooImage")
guard let croppedCGImage = foo?.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 375, height: 400) else { return }
guard let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage) else { return }
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping)

Playground Preview
[image]

**Edit:** Adding example using `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`

[Video showing storyboard/nib usage](https://youtu.be/TEn_4QDl8H0)

```
@IBDesignable
class UIImageViewCroppable: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable public var isCropped: Bool = false {
        didSet { updateImage() }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var croppingRect: CGRect = .zero {
        didSet { updateImage() }
    }

    func updateImage() {
        guard isCropped else { return }
        guard let croppedCGImage = image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: croppingRect) else { return }
        image = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer.

I wish to solve the problem inside of the xib file; but i think there is no way to solve it.

```
imageView.contentMode = .bottom
if let anImage = image.cgImage {
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: anImage, scale: image.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width, orientation: .up)
}
```

Comment: You could create a custom `UIImageView` class that uses `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` to visualize the cropping in a `.xib`, I'll add an example answer to show this.